# Only can type in caps. It acts like the shift key is stuck

Tags: keys

Its not my keyboard. I have tried multiple keyboards.

Everything I type is in CAPS.

When I try and click on a line it acts like the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is held down and selects stuff.

Please Help

Comment: Try pressing <shift> once, does that help?

Comment: If you're typing in to a terminal, please add the results of `stty -a` to your question, or tell us what program you're using, what version of Ubuntu, what hardware, when (before or after last power cycle) the keyboard was connected, how it is connected (USB or PS/2).

Answer (score 9):

This happened to me in Ubuntu 18.04. If you press both <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>caps lock</kbd> the keyboard reverts to its normal behavior. Pressing them both again will change to uppercase and not even tapping <kbd>caps lock</kbd> works to get lower case.

Comment: This worked for me in  Ubuntu 20.04 too.

Answer (score 5):

Check your Universal Access settings. You can find it by going to the Ubuntu Dash (Click the Ubuntu icon at the top left, or press the Super/"Windows" key>), and typing in the word `sticky`. Make sure Sticky keys setting is turned off.

If you press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key for about 5 seconds it should turn the `Shift` sticky on/off.

Comment: @ Seth The Shift Key does not work. @waltinator Im using Ubuntu 12.04 desktop. The keyboard(s) are USB. I can't power down the computer since its running a program I cant close. @ Argusvision The sticky keys are disabled

Comment: Pressing and holding the `Shift` key for five seconds worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I still find this happening occasionally. To avoid a DenverCoder9 situation: I find that if I lock the screen and unlock it, it fixes this.

Answer (score 3):

Double tap the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to turn off all caps.

Answer (score 2):

In **Ubuntu 22.04**, the default activation/deactivation of Caps Lock is **Alt+Caps Lock**. That is, if you have occasionally pressed Alt+CapsLock, you need to press Alt+CapsLock again to disable it. No need to wait for N seconds, the combination just works instantly, once you release the keys.

Comment: If you happen to be working in a Debian/Ubuntu virtual machine hosted on macOS, the proper intervention is `command + caps lock`.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Right-Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to correct this.

Answer (score -2):

Temporary solution
If you are getting lowercase input on shift then try this..

For fedora 34 enable stick keys in the settings and double click shift button to input lowercase letters.

Hopefully work for all linux!!

Comment: This would potentially work for typing but really mess with your other action keys such as CTRL, ALT, Super ++. I do not think this is a solution to the problem, rather a workaround, sadly with little benefit.

Comment: It's not a completely horrible suggestion if all else fails, but I agree that all of the other answers should be tried first.  That said, the original question was asked over 8 years ago since the user couldn't try rebooting the computer due to a long-running program.  Hopefully they've been able to reboot since then ;-).