# Keyboard shift get stuck when entering password with special characters via VNC

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, vnc

## Update

This only seems to be happening when connecting with TightVNC viewer on Winodws. I tried different clients now and none of them showed that issue on first glance...

## Question

I just installed a fresh `Ubuntu 22.04` and am having a very weird issue:

When **entering my password** in any kind of **password field**, the **shift key gets stuck** when reaching the **first special character** in my pwd & I cannot "unstuck" it afterwards.

What that means:

- I can only type ALL UPPER CASE from that moment on
- I cannot select single items in file explorer anymore. It only does "range selection" when clicking on single items as when normally doing shift+click.
- I cannot enter any passwords (correctly) anymore
- Even though this is "triggered" by entering the pwd over VNC, it also affects my locally, physically connected keyboard as that is also in this "shift stuck" mode from now on

The only way I found (until now) to get out of this is state is to reboot the whole machine.
I did try the following without any luck:

- Press shift and/or caps lock (once, multiple times, "double tap", combined, ...)
- Press shift+caps lock (as proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1320639/579685))
- Change active keyboard layout (which has another weird side effect, see below)
- Go to lock screen & re-login (using the on screen keyboard)
- Toggle "sticky keys" accessibility setting

I did not try to log out the user as I cannot use VNC anymore after doing that, so that wouldn't help me as I mostly control the computer via VNC.

Here are some observations I made so far:

- The key gets stuck when reaching the first special character in the pwd.
  E.g. when entering the password on the lock screen with pwd visible, I see the following:
  `mySpecial&PASSWORD` where everything after the first `&` gets capitalized erroneously.
- I only observed this in the following situations (until now):

  - Enter pwd on lock screen (always)
  - Enter pwd in terminal after running command with `sudo` (most of the time, not always...)
  - Enter pwd in the graphical "Authentication required" dialog
  - Enter pwd in login screen of an Ubuntu virtual machine running in VirtualBox.
    Yep, entering the password inside the virtual machine makes the shift key stuck on the host
- This does **not** happen when entering text with special characters somewhere else (VSCode, terminal, ...)
- This only happens when entering the pwd with my physical keyboard (via VNC).
  E.g. I can copy the pwd on my local machine to the clipboard & paste it into the lock screen of the remote screen without any issues.
- This only happens when connected via Ubuntu's built in VNC server. I'm connected via TightVNC viewer on Win 10 which has been working flawless for many years now and I did not try any other client (so far).
  This does **not** happen, when typing the pwd with the locally/physically connected keyboard.
- Ubuntu's built in on screen keyboard is not affected, i.e. I could use it to enter "normal" text when in this state
- Changing the keyboard layout when in this state (e.g. from `de` to `en` & back) results in the following:

  - Shift doesn't seem to be stuck anymore. E.g. single selection in file explorer is working normally afterwards
  - I can **only** type lower case after doing so

I would really appreciate some help with that. Ideally we can find a way to prevent this from happening in the first place but I'd already be happy with a way to "unstuck shift" when in this state without having to reboot the machine.

As mentioned before, I'm controlling this pc almost exclusively via VNC which is rather impossible ATM.

Before this fresh installation, I was using `x11vnc` on `20.04` and did not have any of those issues. However, I can't really go back to this setup as I wasn't able to make `x11vnc` work in `22.04` (different topic) and other options like `xrdp` also came with some "show stopper issues" which I couldn't fully work around (until now)...

Comment: If you can reproduce this, can you try running "xset q" to see if X reports that "Shift Lock" is on when it happens?

Comment: Here's an terrible workaround: Go into settings and set your caps lock behavior to act as "shift lock". Then you can press caps lock before and after everything you originally used shift with

Answer (score 1):

Have been experiencing the same issue. Seem to have resolved it by switching to tigerVNC, hope this helps. I also had the issue occur with both remote and local keyboards, as well as all inputs being affected (not just password inputs) if tightvnc was connected.

Answer (score 0):

What’s worked for me is adding a new language to keyboard and switching to that language then switching back. However it doesn’t work just switching languages - seems like I needed to add and then switch for it to fix. I haven’t tested this thoroughly but it has worked.